# Counting the frequency of keywords in a specified list

Tags: javascript

I am trying to count the number of times specific keywords occur in a string. Let us suppose I have a string and I want to count how many times a few keywords occur in the string. And these keywords are stored in a list. After the program counts the number of times a word occurs it stores it in an array.

I've written the following program

```
var para = "I code code code Javascript"

var keywords = ['code',"I"];

var arr = [];

for(let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++){
    arr[i] = (para.match(/keywords[i]/g) || []).length; 
}
```

keyword[i] doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Would `'coded'` be counted?  Would the `'I'` in `'HI'` be counted?  Or do you want only whole-word matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to solve this is to create the regex first...because `string.match(regex)` accepts a regex as the first argument but you are passing the string`keywords[i]` as the pattern (which will return `0` because that string doesn't exist on `para`) and for that we use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) Constructor to create the regex  that we want to match first then we pass that to `string.match(regex)` :

```js
var para = "I code code code Javascript"

var keywords = ['code',"I"];
var arr = [];

for(let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++){
    var reg = new RegExp(keywords[i],'g')
    arr[i] = (para.match(reg) || []).length; 
    console.log(arr[i])
}
```

Comment: why use `${keywords[i]}` instead of just  `new RegExp(keywords[i],'g')`, really no benefit.

Comment: This answer screams out for a `map` call.

Comment: @epascarello true , thought the `regExp ` accepts only a `string` so if the `keywords` includes a `number` it will be converted . you could've suggested an edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to create a sort of count map:

```js
const getKeywordCount = (s, keywords) => {
  return s.split(' ').reduce((accum, word) => {
    if (keywords.includes(word)) {
      accum[word] = accum[word] ? accum[word] + 1 : 1;
    }
    return accum;
  }, {});
};

console.log(getKeywordCount("I code code code Javascript", ['code', "I"]))
```

Comment: I personally prefer this answer because it doesn't use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just split the sting instead

```
let para = "I code code code Javascript";

let sentence = para.split(' ');

let keywords = ['code','I'];

let arr = [];

sentence.forEach(function (element1) {

    let count = 0;

    keywords.forEach(function (element2) {
        if(element1 === element2) count++;
    });

    arr.push(count);

    console.log(count);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well

```
    function count(...arg) {
    var para;
    var keywords = [];
    var t = 0;
    arg.forEach(e => {
        if (t == 0) {
            para = e;
        } else {
            keywords.push(e);
        }
        t++;
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        para += '';
        let subStr = keywords[i].replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
        let f = (para.match(new RegExp(subStr, 'gi')) || []).length;

        console.log("Frequency of " + keywords[i] + " : " + f);
    }
}

count("I code code code Javascript", 'code', 'I'); 
//call count like count("paragraph","keyword1","keyword2",...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an array of the counts, this would do:

```js
const getCounts = (keywords, para) =>
  keywords .map (k => para .match (new RegExp (k, 'g')) .length)

var para = "I code code code Javascript"
var keywords = ['code',"I"];

console .log (
  getCounts (keywords, para)
)
```

If you want an object mapping the keywords to their counts, this might be better:

```js
const getCounts = (keywords, para) =>
  keywords .reduce ((a, k) => ({...a, [k]: para .match (new RegExp(k, 'g')) .length}), {})

var para = "I code code code Javascript"
var keywords = ['code',"I"];

console .log (
  getCounts (keywords, para)
)
```